# Ray tracing intersection test by transforming the ray

Tags: raytracing

I'm trying to implement a basic ray tracer, which involve transform each ray into each object space and test intersection with the affinely deformed object by multiply the inverse of the affine transformation matrix with the ray. The intersection test is correct when the object is rotated, scaled, but not translated. When the object is translated (and the object should be still viewable), the intersection test fail, and no object is displayed.

Comment: Please, be more explict about your question and if you can, share some code to help people to answer the question.

Answer (score 1):

When applying transformations the order of the operation is important. Applying them in the different orders gives you a different result.

For example, let's say you have a box with the centre at (0,0,0). You now rotate, then translate the box. The rotation will happen with respect to the origin of the coordinate system.

If you instead start by translating the box, say to (1,0,0), then do the rotation. The box will still rotate with respect to the centre of the coordinate system. However, the box is now longer at the centre of the coordinate system so it swings around in an arc.

[This is a useful write-up about order of transformations](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/eews39w7.aspx)

If you already knew about all this then sorry.

The only other thing I can do is point you in the direction of my [ray tracing project on github pvtrace](https://github.com/danieljfarrell/pvtrace). It's all written in Python and you should be able to use it to debug your intersection code. If has different primitive shapes with which you can apply transformations too. The transformations are all applied by using the append_transformation() method of the primitives. All transformations are 4x4 homogeneous matrices which are passed to this method. The homogeneous matrices themselves are constructed using [transformations.py](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/) which is bundled with the source code.

I hope that helps.